# Как должно выглядеть окно конфигурации IntelliJ IDEA для Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Ошибки которые выдает:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.company.Main Caused by: 
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.Main 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Путь к файлу: C:\Projects\Java\src\com\company\Main.java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка "класс не найден". Приложите его в вопрос, может там нет в указанном файле? И попробуйте указать working directory: `C:\Projects\Java\src`.

Comment: Как по мне, не указано еще `main\java` после `src` , т.е. путь к файлу должен выглядеть так: `C:\Projects\Java\src\main\java\com\company\Main.java`. Как создадите, правой кнопкой мыши и кликнуть на `java` и далее в меню: `Mark Directory as/Sources root`. После этого idea должна подхватить ваш файл.